# Assigning a pre-determined value to an input variable if not specified

Tags: c++

I have a variable as an input which you should be able to initialize or not.
Trying to explain better through code:

`double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u, double dt)`

I want to have the possibility to initialize dt as 0.1 if it's not specified by the user.
For example:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << simulate(2.5, 1.2, 6.2, 3.0);
}
```

But the user should have the possibility to overwrite the standard value in order to let him choose the best fit value:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << simulate(2.5, 1.2, 6.2, 3.0, 0.0);
}
```

Comment: Use a default argument, or overload the function. Passing `std::optional` can work too - then you can have default values anywhere in the parameter list although the default values are not quite so explicit. By the way it looks like `dt` is a time step. Repeated addition of `0.1` can cause your model to go off quite significantly due to floating point rounding. As an alternative, pass the total time and the number of steps. If your having fun implementing gravitational fields for example, it will certainly have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a default parameter is the easiest solution:

```cpp
double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u, double dt = 0.1);

int main() {
    std::cout << simulate(2.5, 1.2, 6.2, 3.0);
    std::cout << simulate(2.5, 1.2, 6.2, 3.0, 0.0);
}
```

Another option is to overload the function:

```cpp
double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u, double dt);

double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u) {
    return simulate(a, b, x, u, 0.1);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << simulate(2.5, 1.2, 6.2, 3.0);
    std::cout << simulate(2.5, 1.2, 6.2, 3.0, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) when declaring your function:

```
double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u, double dt = 0.1) { /* ... */ }
```

Invocation of `simulate(...)` while supplying only 4 out of 5 arguments will use the default argument value `0.1` for the final parameter `dt`, whereas the user of the API may choose to override the default argument for the `dt` function parameter by supplying it as an explicit fifth argument.

Answer (score 2):

That's what [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) are for. It's simple:

```
double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u, double dt = 0.1)
```

This allows the caller to leave out the `dt` argument if they want to use the default.

Default arguments must come after all others.

Be sure to add the default value either in the declaration, or in the definition of your function, not both.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you can use a default argument:

```
double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u, double dt = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a default value, which makes the last parameter optional:

```
double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u, double dt = 0.1)
```

or overload the function

```
double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u, double dt);
double simulate(double a, double b, double x, double u)
{
    return simulate(a, b, x, u, 0.1);
}
```